# Doctrine - create One To Many with Join Table in YAML

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, yaml

Im trying to create a one To Many relationship between a User and a Role with a join table.
I have not managed been able to find a YAML example in the [doctrine docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table)

How would i declare an equivalent relationship with YAML?

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection $userRoles
 */
protected $userRoles;
```

YAML files:

```
Acme\AcmeBundle\User:
  type: entity
  table: null
  fields:
  id:
    type: integer
    id: true
    generator:
    strategy: AUTO
  forename:
    type: string
    length: 255
  surname:
    type: string
    length: 255
  email:
    type: string
    length: 255
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }

Acme\AcmeBundle\Role:      
  type: entity
  table: null
  fields:
  id:
    type: integer
    id: true
    generator:
    strategy: AUTO
  name:
    type: string
    length: 255
  createdAt:
    type: datetime
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: Are trying to migrate the same relationship from SF1 to SF2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Acme\AcmeBundle\User:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
      roles:
          targetEntity: Role
          joinTable:
              name: user_role
              joinColumns:
                  user_id:
                      referencedColumnName: id
              inverseJoinColumns:
                  role:
                      referencedColumnName: id
  table: null
  fields:
  id:
    type: integer
    id: true
    generator:
    strategy: AUTO
  forename:
    type: string
    length: 255
  surname:
    type: string
    length: 255
  email:
    type: string
    length: 255
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: Also, looks like you're doing ManyToMany, not OneToMany